# Using 2 key pairs simultaneously for ssh authentication

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, raspbian, ssh-keygen

I have a ssh server running on a raspberry pi. This ssh server can only be accessed by 1 user on my ubuntu laptop only.

I have created 2 pairs of ssh keys using:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -o -a 100 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -a 100
```

The 2 public keys have been appended to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the ssh server.

When I view the authorized_keys file, it is as below:

```
ssh-ed25519 ...
ssh-rsa ...
```

What I want is a dual authentication where BOTH key pairs are verified before establishing ssh connection. In my case, I have noticed that it is possible to connect whenever I have 1 key pair authenticated.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can configure your server to require multiplie public keys, as documented in the [`AuthenticationMethods`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#AuthenticationMethods) *sshd_config* keyword:

> If the publickey method is listed more than once, sshd(8) verifies
>   that **keys that have been used successfully are not reused** for
>   subsequent authentications. For example, **“publickey,publickey”
>   requires successful authentication using two different public keys**.

So to test this on a single user named *test*, one can add this at the end of the `sshd_config` file (and reload configuration):

```
Match User test
    AuthenticationMethods publickey,publickey
```

And then add the two public keys in `~test/.ssh/authorized_keys` as usual.

On the client side, if keys aren't readily available for example with a running *ssh-agent* one should supply both keys as parameters like for example:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 test@server
```